# How to prove that removing any set of k vertices from a graph that has a hamiltonian cycle can leave at most k connected components?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

This is from this article https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~rytter/TEACHING/ALCOMB/schwenk.pdf about the Knight's Tour. I am not sure I understand why this is true. I attempted to prove it by induction. I said that when 1 vertex is removed, there will 1 connected component because that vertex can't be a cut vertex. However, from there I don't know what to do.

Comment: If you take a necklace and cut it at $k$ points, how many pieces do you have?

Comment: I understand that, but how would I go about proving this for more complicated graphs that have several vertices with degree more than 2?

Comment: How about uncomplicating them? Start by cutting away all edges not in your Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: Wow, I was over complicating it so much. It's so obvious now. Thank you!